# Use Mongoose aggregate to retrieve data of array inside of a schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema in MongoDB like this.

```
{
productID:1,
reviews:
[
{
_id:1
likes:[{userID:1},{userID:2}],
dislikes:[{userID:3},{userID:4}],
comment:"first comment"
},
{
_id:2
likes:[{userID:1},{userID:2}],
dislikes:[{userID:3},{userID:4}],
comment:"first comment"
}
]
}
```

I want to fetch the likes count of a userID of a particular review for example like count of userID 2 of review id 2. I tried to get it with the help of aggregate but got stuck.

this is the code that I tried.

```
  ProductReview.aggregate([
    { $match: { productID: productID } },
    { $match: {reviews._id:_id}}
 ])
```

but it looks like I am messing with the mongoose syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to get number of likes for each review or number of likes by each user for each review. Are users allowed to like the same review multiple times?

Comment: this is just random schema. I just tried to check whether userid existed in the likes array of a review or not as one user can only like the review at once.

Comment: In that case you can use `$addToSet` instead of trying to get count. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get likes by user on particular reviews then use this query
You will have to pass productID, reviewsID and userID

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
        $match: {
            "productID": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$reviews"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "reviews._id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$reviews.likes"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "reviews.likes.userID": 2
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$reviews.likes",
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            userID: "$_id.userID",
            count: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wUC5tbnLC47

**OLD**
**This returns for all reviews**
Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ob5BLCAHrw1
if you want both likes and dislikes of users with one query you can use $facet
Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LELfQfKjw_h